# C# IndexOutof RangeException

Tags: c#, arrays, mono

I am getting an System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array. at EvEOreCalculator.Program.Main() when I try to run my compiled code (I am using C#).  The values can range up into the 5 billion area for the inputs from the user.  All of the int variables and arrays that held large numbers have already been converted to long.  The only ints left are just inside a standard for loop to iterate across arrays.

I was not having any issues untill I corrected the data in the compressedOreList array, both that array and orelist were ints until I started getting the out of range exception, it ran fine as an int and the numbers in both tables were just as long before I made the changes, all that changed were the digits themselves.

This is basically a proof of concept console app that I am going to change into a windows form app, I am trying to ensure that the mathematics behind it are correct.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace EvEOreCalculator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            //array to store the input values from the user

            //minerals[5] = new int inputZ;
            //minerals[6] = new int inputMega;

            /*
            Due to the amounts of Nocxium, Zydrine and Megacyte used in even titans being negligible in terms of space 
            (a Titan worth of Nocxium is not even half a JF) and to reduce the amounts of complexity of the problem
            as well as only wanting to account for high sec ores as they are the most available in trade hubs and thus most likely to be used,
            Nocxium totals will be subtracted if Pyroxeres is needed and will be removed from the total that is 
            sent back to the user.
            */

            //In the following array, the data is from left to right: {Tritanium, Pyerite, Mexallon, Isogen, Nocxium, Zydrine, Megacyte, and then
            //the volume per batch in meters cubed};
            //if a maximum volume is needed to reference use 367000m3
            long[,] orelist = new long[5, 8]
            {
            //high sec ores, very common
            {415,   0,      0,      0,      0,      0,      0,      10}, //POS 0 Veldspar 41.5 Trit/m3  
            {346,   173,    0,      0,      0,      0,      0,      15}, //POS 1 Scordite  23.0666 T/m3
            {351,   25,     50,     0,      5,      0,      0,      30}, //POS 2 Pyroxeres  11.7 T/m3
            {107,   213,    107,    0,      0,      0,      0,      35}, //POS 3 Plagioclase   3.057 t/m3
            {85,    34,     0,      85,     0,      0,      0,      60}, //POS 4 Omber      1.4166 t/m3
        //  {134,   0,      267,    134,    0,      0,      0,      120} //POS 5 Kernite   1.116666 t/m3
            };
            long[,] compressedOreList = new long[5, 6]
            {
            {690500,    0,          0,          0,          0,      257},//POS 0 compressed Veldspar
            {345112,    172349,     0,          0,          0,      193},//POS 1 compressed Scordite            
            {174835,    12222,      24858,      0,          2279,   80},//POS 2 compressed Pyroxeres            
            {35354,     70708,      35354,      0,          0,      53},//POS 3 compressed Plagioclase          
            {21199,     8494,       0,          21199,      0,      19},//POS 4 compressed Omber            
        //  {11580,     0,          23191,      11580,      0,      720} //POS 5 compressed Kernite
            };
            /*
            //Jaspet is garbage so it is excluded
            //orelist[6] = new int[8] {72,  121,    144,    0,      72,     0,      3,      200}; //Jaspet    0.36 t/m3


            //null sec ores, less common on market
            orelist[11] = new int[8]{6905,  0,      0,      0,      0,      230,    115,    1600}};  //Arkonor  4.315625 t/m3
            orelist[12] = new int[8]{0,     8286,   0,      0,      0,      118,    235,    1600};  //Bistot 
            orelist[14] = new int[8]{39221, 4972,   0,      0,      0,      78,     0,      1600} //Spodumain   24.5131 t/m3
            orelist[13] = new int[8]{20992, 0,      0,      0,      183,    0,      367,    1600}; //Crokite   13.12 t/m3

            //low sec ores, 
            orelist[7] = new int[8] {180,   72,     17,     159,    118,    0,      8,      300}; //Hemorphite  0.6 t/m3
            orelist[8] = new int[8] {0,     81,     0,      196,    98,     0,      9,      300};  //Hedbergite
            orelist[9] = new int[8] {1278,  0,      1278,   242,    0,      0,      60,     500};  //Gneiss   2.556 t/m3
            orelist[10] = new int[8]{8804,  0,      0,      0,      173,    0,      87,     800};  //Dark_Ochre  11.005 t/m3
            */

            //asking the user to input the amount of each mineral they need to carry
            //mineralsT array is  from left to right: {Tritanium, Pyerite, Mexallon, Isogen, Nocxium}
            long[] mineralsT = new long[5];

            Console.WriteLine("How much Tritanium:");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            mineralsT[0] =  long.Parse(input);
            //mineralsT[0] = Convert.ToInt32(input);

            Console.WriteLine("How much Pyerite:");
            string input1 = Console.ReadLine();
            mineralsT[1] = long.Parse(input1);

            Console.WriteLine("How much Mexallon:");
            string input2 = Console.ReadLine();
            mineralsT[2] = long.Parse(input2);

            Console.WriteLine("How much Isogen:");
            string input3 = Console.ReadLine();
            mineralsT[3] = long.Parse(input3);

            Console.WriteLine("How much Nocxium:");
            string input4 = Console.ReadLine();
            mineralsT[4] = long.Parse(input4);

            //Console.WriteLine("How much Zydrine:");
            //inputI = Console.ReadLine();
            //Console.WriteLine("How much Megacyte:");
            //inputI = Console.ReadLine();


            long[] oresTcount = new long[10];

            while (mineralsT[0] > 0)
            {
                while (mineralsT[3] > 0) //Isogen
                {
                    /*while (mineralsT[2] >= compressedOreList[2])
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                        {
                            mineralsT[i] = mineralsT[i] - compressedOreList[5, i];
                        }
                        oresTcount[11]++;
                    }*/

                    while(mineralsT[3] >= compressedOreList[4, 3])  //compressed Omber
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                        {
                            mineralsT[i] = mineralsT[i] - compressedOreList[4, i];
                        }
                        oresTcount[10]++;
                    }

                /*    while(mineralsT[3] < compressedOreList[4, 3] && mineralsT[2] >= compressedOreList[5, 3]) //compressed Kernite
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                        {
                            mineralsT[i] = mineralsT[i] - compressedOreList[5, i];
                        }
                        oresTcount[11]++;
                    } 

                    while (mineralsT[2] < compressedOreList[5, 3] && mineralsT[2] >= 267 )  //Kernite
                     {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                        {
                            mineralsT[i] = mineralsT[i] - orelist[5, i];
                        }
                        oresTcount[11]++;
                    } */

                    while(mineralsT[2] < 267 && mineralsT[3] > 0)  //Omber
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                        {
                            mineralsT[i] = mineralsT[i] - orelist[4, i];
                        }
                        oresTcount[4] = oresTcount[4]+100;
                    }
                   // Console.WriteLine("Derp");
                }

                while (mineralsT[2] > 0)  //Mexallon
                {
                    while(mineralsT[2] >= compressedOreList[2, 2] && mineralsT[4] >= compressedOreList[2,4]) //compressed Pyroxeres
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                        {
                            mineralsT[i] = mineralsT[i] - compressedOreList[2, i];
                        }
                        oresTcount[8]++;                    
                    } 
                    while(mineralsT[2] >= compressedOreList[3, 2]) //compressed Plagioclase
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                        {
                            mineralsT[i] = mineralsT[i] - compressedOreList[3, i];
                        }
                        oresTcount[9]++;                    
                    }

                    if (mineralsT[2] <= compressedOreList[2, 2] && mineralsT[2]  >= 107  )  //Plagioclase
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                        {
                            mineralsT[i] = mineralsT[i] - orelist[3, i];
                        }
                        oresTcount[3] = oresTcount[3]+100;
                    }

                    else if (mineralsT[2] < 107) //Pyroxeres
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                        {
                            mineralsT[i] = mineralsT[i] - orelist[2, i];
                        }
                        oresTcount[2] = oresTcount[2]+100;
                    }
                   // Console.WriteLine("Derp1");
                }

                while (mineralsT[1] > 0) //Pyerite
                {
                    while (mineralsT[1] >= compressedOreList[1,1])  //Compressed Scordite
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                        {
                            mineralsT[i] = mineralsT[i] - compressedOreList[1, i];
                        }
                        oresTcount[7]++;
                    }

                    while (mineralsT[1] < compressedOreList[1,1] && mineralsT[1] > 0)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                        {
                            mineralsT[i] = mineralsT[i] - orelist[1, i];
                        }
                        oresTcount[1] = oresTcount[1]+100;
                    }

                }

                while (mineralsT[1] <= 0 && mineralsT[2] <= 0 && mineralsT[3] <= 0 && mineralsT[0] >= compressedOreList[0,0]) //compressed Veldspar
                {
                    mineralsT[0] = mineralsT[0] - compressedOreList[0, 0];
                    oresTcount[6]++;
                }
                if    (mineralsT[1] <= 0 && mineralsT[2] <= 0 && mineralsT[3] <= 0 && mineralsT[0] <= compressedOreList[0,0])//Veldspar
                {
                   mineralsT[0] = mineralsT[0] - orelist[0, 0];
                   oresTcount[0] = oresTcount[0]+100;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(mineralsT[0] + "T" + mineralsT[1] + "P" + mineralsT[2] + "M" + mineralsT[3] + "I" + mineralsT[4] + "N");

            Console.WriteLine("Compressed Veldspar:" + oresTcount[6]);
            Console.WriteLine("Veldspar:" + oresTcount[0]);
            Console.WriteLine("");

            Console.WriteLine("Compressed Scordite:" + oresTcount[7]);
            Console.WriteLine("Scordite:" + oresTcount[1]);
            Console.WriteLine("");

            Console.WriteLine("Compressed Pyroxeres:" + oresTcount[8]);
            Console.WriteLine("Pyroxeres:" + oresTcount[2]);
            Console.WriteLine("");

            Console.WriteLine("Compressed Plagioclase:" + oresTcount[9]);
            Console.WriteLine("Plagioclase:" + oresTcount[3]);
            Console.WriteLine("");

            Console.WriteLine("Compressed Omber:" + oresTcount[10]);
            Console.WriteLine("Omber:" + oresTcount[4]);
            Console.WriteLine("");

           /* Console.WriteLine("Compressed Kernite:" + oresTcount[11]);
            Console.WriteLine("Kernite:" + oresTcount[5]);
            Console.WriteLine(""); */

            long TotalV = new long();

            TotalV = ((oresTcount[0] * orelist[0,7]) + 
            (oresTcount[1] * orelist[1,7]) +    
            (oresTcount[2] * orelist[2,7]) + 
            (oresTcount[3] * orelist[3,7]) + 
            (oresTcount[4] * orelist[4,7]) +

            (oresTcount[6] * compressedOreList[0,5]) + 
            (oresTcount[7] * compressedOreList[1,5]) + 
            (oresTcount[8] * compressedOreList[2,5]) + 
            (oresTcount[9] * compressedOreList[3,5]) +
            (oresTcount[10] * compressedOreList[4,5]));

            Console.WriteLine("Total Volume:" + TotalV);
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's *a lot* of code for us to casually read.  Can you maybe narrow it down a bit?

Comment: Do you know what line the problem happens on? Do you see a stack trace? Do you know how to _read_ a stack trace?

Comment: The exception tells you very clearly about the **"why"/"what"**: "*System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array*". Check the stack trace of the exception to find out which code line causes this exception (the **"where"**). Then study your source code and use the debugger to find out why your code uses an invalid array index...

Comment: Importantly, what were the values you entered at each `Console.ReadLine`?

Comment: The running the executable with the mono debugger gives      "Unhandled Exception:
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.
  at EvEOreCalculator.Program.Main () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index
is out of range.
  at EvEOreCalculator.Program.Main () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0"

Comment: The last Console.ReadLine is just to force to program not to close.  The first few Console.Readlines are values from 5billion down to 1million.

Comment: I know that the logic all works correctly as the program ran with large numbers before I changed the values in the compressedOreList array.  As I stated in the first post, those numbers only changed by +/- 200,000.  They were still between 200,000 and 500,000 for most of the values.

Comment: Compile a debug build and run it in the debugger, do not use a release build for debugging...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first look, not sure if it is the only problem, but you declare

```
 long[] oresTcount = new long[10];
```

and then call

```
 oresTcount[10]++;
```

The max available index for the `oresTcount` array is 9, (10 elements from index 0 to 9) so, if you want to use index 10 you need to declare the array with

```
 long[] oresTcount = new long[11];
```

by the way, the value at index 5 is not printed neither used in your code.

Comment: That was the problem, I can't believe I missed that.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you'd actually **read** the stack trace from your exception, you'd see that that failing line is

```
oresTCount[10]++;
```

That variable, `oresTCount`, is defined as `new long[10]`, meaning its indices has the domain  0–9 inclusive. 10 is right out.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in your use of oresTcount.  It is defined as:

```
long[] oresTcount = new long[10];
```

But you have references to oresTcount[10]:

```
oresTcount[10]++;
```

and

```
Console.WriteLine("Compressed Omber:" + oresTcount[10]);
```

You can only reference indexes 0-9 with the current definition of oresTcount.

You should be able to look at the exception's stack trace to verify the line that is causing the exception.